# prevent google to index dynamic error pages (none 404)

Tags: seo, indexing, http-status-code-404, search-engine, google-crawlers

There are some none `404` error pages on my website. what is the best way to stop google from indexing them?

**option 1**

```
header("HTTP/1.0 410 Gone");
```

what if the content is not gone? for example: `the article does not exist.` or `wrong parameter has been caught`

**option 2**

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

does it only affect one page or the whole domain?

**option 3**

using 404 which will make some other problems and I would like to avoid.

**robot.txt**

this option will not work since the error will depend on the database and is not static.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @JohnConde it is about what code to write :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to do a 301 redirect to similar content on your site if content is removed.

To stop Google indexing certain areas of your site use [robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en)

UPDATE: If you send a `200 OK` and add the robots meta tag (Option 2 in your question) - this should do what you want.

Comment: robot.txt wont help here. error pages depend on the database and we dont know from before when they occur. 301 prevents user from seeing the error message in the main frame of the page.

Comment: Ok - this was not clear from your question. What do you mean "301 prevents user from seeing error message?". You can still serve a "Not found" page with an HTTP 200. Would that work? What server-side language are you using?

Comment: I use PHP. if I redirect to another page, I cannot show the error message to user simply. If I show error with code 200, the problem will be the threat of page indexing.

Comment: Show page with 200 then, and add the meta tag with <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />?

Comment: thanks. seems i should do that. by googling i found `X-Robots-Tag` but i am not sure if they are useful or not.

Comment: @faravish No problem. Please mark as answer if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

One way to prevent google bots to index something is using robots files:

```
User-agent: googlebot
Disallow: /mypage.html
Disallow: /mp3/
```

This way you can manually disable single pages or entire directories.

Comment: error pages are dynamic and they depend on the database.

Comment: Then this is probably no use to you unless you manage to auto-generate them. I quite don't like the idea though. Can you put the error pages all ensemble into a single directory and disable the indexing for that one only?